# Where does application.js code go in rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Prior to rails 3.1, javascript code that was common to the application belonged in application.js by default, and was loaded by `javascript_include_tag :defaults`

With the asset pipeline in rails 3.1, the application.js file becomes a manifest file, and it appears that code I put in it is not included in the result.  Where is this javascript code supposed to be moved to now?  Obviously, I could create any other name and make sure that it is included by the manifest, but is there a default location already expected by idiom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encounter the same problem in rails 3.1 rc6. I use `javascript_include_tag :application` instead

Answer (score 0):

Look closer:

the code in `application.js` is rendered, it's just at the end of the resulting js file.

Example, try:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
alert('foo');
```

the alert dialog will appear in all pages.

Comment: I did that, and it is not appearing.

Comment: I think it has do do with :defaults not working, so I replaced with the libraries and left application out. So should `javascript_include_tag :defaults, 'script1', ...` be replaced with `javascript_include_tag 'application' (and the other scripts loaded by the manifest)?